# How to resolve self reference in this case?

Tags: scala, this, self

For the two blocks of code, i expected the `self` reference in both blocks to be Foo[A]. However it seems the second block does not compile. Can someone explain to me how to resolve the `self` references?

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def format(value:A):String
  def bar[B](f:B=>A):Foo[B] = {
    val self = this
    new Foo[B] {
      override def format(value: B): String = self.format(f(value))
    }
  }
}

trait Foo[A] {
  def format(value:A):String
  val self = this
  def bar[B](f:B=>A):Foo[B] = {      
    new Foo[B] {
      override def format(value: B): String = self.format(f(value))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` get assigned `this`, which is a reference to a particular instance, the one you're calling a method (or a constructor) at invocation.

In the first snippet, you invoke the method `bar` on an object of type `Foo[A]`, meaning that at that point `this` means the instance of `Foo[A]`. After you assign `this` to `self` you proceed to create a new instance of `Foo`, this time giving the type parameter a different type, but `self`.

In the second snippet you are saying that objects of type `Foo[A]` have a member field that is called `self` and gets assigned `this`. This will apply to all instances of `Foo[_]`, regardless of how you call the type parameter. When you create a second `Foo` calling the type parameter `B`, this second instance will nonetheless have a member field `self`, which gets assigned `this`, which at this point is `Foo[B]` and *shades* the `self` that you declared as part of the initial declaration of `Foo`.

This means that in the second snippet, you the `format` method implementation of `Foo[B]` has access to a `self` reference of `Foo[B]` itself, which causes the type error you mentioned.

- Foo[B] has method format(value: B)
- method `bar` takes a function that takes a `B` and transforms it into an `A`
- You apply `f: B => A` to `value: B`, turning it into an `A`, then you try to feed `A` to `Foo[B]#format(value: B)`

Sorry for the convoluted response; in short: type parameters are mere placeholder names for actual types just like value parameters are placeholder names for actual runtime values. Apply the same reasoning to both types and values and reasoning about them will become easier.

Comment: Good catch. I was scratching my head. `private[this] val self:Foo[A] = this` and it compiles just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to explain this thoroughly. I got it. For others who might not get it I think it helps to substitute A and B with some concrete time first before abstracting.